# Why NTFS write softwares cause some certain problems?

Tags: bootcamp, parallels-desktop, ntfs

After installing NTFS write software on my mac, I found two problems.

1. The Windows system in bootcamp does not show in the startup disk in Settings app.
2. Parallels Desktop can't suspend the Bootcamp virtual machine because such software installed.

Both the problems can be solved by removing the software.

What's the reason behind this?

Comment: I don't know why, but it does. Paragon NTFS has an option to disable the driver to get around just this issue. You also should never suspend your Boot Camp volume in VM if you want to boot from it in Boot Camp; it can cause corruption.

Answer (score 1):

You do not mention what software you're using to mount the NTFS volume read/write in OS X, nor which version of Parallels you're using, nor do you say what model Mac you have.  This is important to give you accurate information.

Paragon NTFS works with Parallels just fine.  MacFUSE or other NTFS read/write utilities do not.  Also, Parallels 8 and lower have issues with Paragon HFS if you have that installed on the Windows side.

Also, you should never suspend the Parallels Boot Camp VM.  If you attempt to boot to Windows via Boot Camp while the Parallels VM is suspended, you can cause data corruption.

Answer (score 0):

I will conjecture here; feel free to downvote if you think I'm completely off-base:

Perhaps the NTFS utility puts the NTFS volume "in use". That is, other OS's try to access the disk but they can tell MacFUSE is already using the disk (or so they think). They're programmed to not interfere with other disk operations so they take a 'hands off' attitude so as to prevent data corruption that would result if two systems tried to write the same data at the same time.

As to why MacFUSE would leave the disk busy when it's not even using it (or running), that would be a question for the developers.